# Can the derivative of a conformal homeomorphism onto a bounded domain be unbounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Consider $f$ being a holomorphic homeomorphism of the closed unit disk into the complex plane (ie. $f$ must be a homeomorphism - which also imply bijectivity to its image - of the closed unit disk, it must be holomorphic in the interior of the disk, and the image of the closed disk cannot contains infinity).

- Must $f^{\prime}$ in the interior of the disk be bounded?
- (if the answer to the above is no) Can there be an infinite number of point on the unit circle such that $f^{\prime}$ is unbounded in every neighbourhood of that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative $f'$ can be unbounded. Consider a conformal map from the disk to the square. Four points of the boundary, say $\zeta_1,\dots,\zeta_4$, are mapped to vertices, where the interior angle is $\pi/2$. This means that near $\zeta_k$ the map behaves like $c(z-\zeta_k)^{1/2}$ and its derivative like $\frac{c}{2}(z-\zeta_k)^{-1/2}$. The [Schwarz–Christoffel mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping#Other_simple_mappings) makes this intuition precise.

The map is a homeomorphism of closures, since the square is a Jordan domain.

To make this happen at infinitely many boundary points, we need a Jordan domain with infinitely many vertices of interior angle less than $\pi$. There are many ways to do this. One construction is to take the convex hull of the points $\{\exp(i/n):  n=0,1,2,3,4,\dots \}$; these points will be vertices. Another is to   let the domain be $\{x+iy:0<x<1, |x\sin(1/x)|<y<1\}$: the bottom boundary is shown below.

[image: sine]

For maximal insanity, imagine conformally mapping the disk onto the domain bounded by [Koch snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake). And this example isn't even really bad: the interior of snowflake has   good geometry from the conformal viewpoint, but the boundary behavior is weird.